# Count of multiple items in one MySQL query returns an incorrect result

Tags: mysql, count

Say, if I define my tables as such:

```
create table `usrs` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`fnm` TINYTEXT,
`lnm` TINYTEXT
);

insert into `usrs` (`fnm`, `lnm`)
VALUES
('John', 'Doe'),    -- 1
('Mary', 'Smith'),  -- 2
('Peter', 'Pan'),   -- 3
('Michael', 'Jackson'); -- 4
```

[image]

```
create table `pmts` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`uid` INT UNSIGNED, -- id in `usrs` table
`amt` DOUBLE,
`flgs` INT UNSIGNED
);

insert into `pmts` (`uid`, `amt`, `flgs`)
VALUES
('3', '0.99', 0),
('1', '1.50', 0x80),
('3', '2',    0x80),
('3', '0.99', 0),
('4', '1.30', 0),
('3', '2.40', 0),
('1', '2.55', 0x80);
```

[image]

```
create table `downloads` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`uid` INT UNSIGNED, -- id in `usrs` table
`app` TINYTEXT
);

insert into `downloads` (`uid`, `app`)
VALUES
('2', 'Candy Crush'),
('2', 'Skype'),
('3', 'Word'),
('2', 'Calc'),
('4', 'Doom'),
('3', 'Notepad');
```

[image]

Then when I run this query, that among other things counts `pmts`, `downloads` and special `flgs` for each `usr`:

```
-- this query contains additional clauses that were used in my production query

SELECT t1.*, 
COUNT(t2.`id`) as cPmts,                        -- count `pmts` for each user
SUM(IF((t2.`flgs`&0x80)<>0, 1, 0)) as cPmtFlgs, -- count `pmts` with `flgs` equal to 0x80 for each user
COUNT(t3.`id`) as cDwds                         -- count `downloads` for each user
FROM `usrs` t1
LEFT JOIN `pmts` t2 ON t1.`id`=t2.`uid`
LEFT JOIN `downloads` t3 ON t1.`id`=t3.`uid`
WHERE t1.`id` > 0   -- just to simulate some condition
GROUP BY t1.`id`
ORDER BY t1.`fnm`, t1.`lnm` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

the results I receive, marked in red, are wrong:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that because `Peter Pan` has multiple payments *and* multiple downloads, his rows are being duplicated in the `JOIN` (you can see this if you remove the `GROUP BY` and replace the aggregation functions in the query with a simple `SELECT *` [[demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a793eb/8)). The way to work around this is to perform the aggregations in derived tables and `JOIN` those results instead:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
COALESCE(t2.cPmts, 0) AS cPmts,                        -- count `pmts` for each user
COALESCE(t2.cPmtFlgs, 0) AS cPmtFlgs, -- count `pmts` with `flgs` equal to 0x80 for each user
COALESCE(t3.cDwds, 0) AS cDwds                         -- count `downloads` for each user
FROM `usrs` t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, 
           COUNT(*) AS cPmts,
           SUM(IF((`flgs`&0x80)<>0, 1, 0)) AS CpmtFlgs
           FROM `pmts`
           GROUP BY uid) t2 ON t1.`id`=t2.`uid`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, COUNT(*) AS cDwds
           FROM `downloads`
           GROUP BY uid) t3 ON t1.`id`=t3.`uid`
WHERE t1.`id` > 0   -- just to simulate some condition
ORDER BY t1.`fnm`, t1.`lnm` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Output:

```
id  fnm         lnm         cPmts   cPmtFlgs    cDwds
1   John        Doe         2       2           0
2   Mary        Smith       0       0           3
4   Michael     Jackson     1       0           1
3   Peter       Pan         4       1           2
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a793eb/3)

Comment: @Nick: thanks. I didn't think about using `SELECT`s as a part of `LEFT JOIN`s like that. I learned something today. One thing that comes to mind though -- wouldn't it make the overall query run much slower then?

Comment: @c00000fd This is really the only option here, because doing it the way you originally had it would run the risk of double counting.

Comment: @c00000fd with appropriate indexes on `uid` in `pmts` and `downloads` it shouldn't be significantly slower as you will gain some improvement by only having to `JOIN` one row from each derived table. More to the point though, this is the only way to avoid double counting.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help, guys.